# Contract in WCF and getters and setter in - generated WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf

I have something like:

```
[DataContract]
class A 
{

    [DataMember]
    public int name { get; set; }  
}
```

For this above version 1. of class in WSDL there is no field `name`.

```
[DataContract]
class A 
{

    [DataMember]
    public int name;

    public int Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

In above version 2. I can see a field `Name` in generated `WSDL`.
What should I do to make version 1. in such way that generated `WSDL` can see field `name` ??

Comment: Side note: In 2. `name` should be `private`.

Comment: ... and the `[DataMember]` should be on `public int Name`.

Comment: use "public" access modifier for class A in version 1.